# No UI on Substrate Playground from firefox or chrome under Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: playground

I'm trying to experiment with [substrate playground](https://substrate.io/developers/playground/), but after accepting terms and starting an instance, there is no UI, just a blank screen where the IDE should be. I have attached an image. I've tried it in both Chrome and Firefox. In chrome the console logs the following:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()
```

and

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

Under Firefox, the following:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://myusername.playground.substrate.dev/bundle.js”.
```

All ad/cookie blockers are disabled, as well as any NoScript addons or settings.

I have attached an image of the screen I am seeing when I should get the IDE.[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Works fine for me. Do you have any browser add-ons enabled that might interrupt the proper functioning of the playground?

Comment: Working fine this morning, haven't changed any settings (or even restarted since yesterday) and I'm on the same network, I will leave this thread open in case I see any issues but for now it's working, thanks for your reply Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, an unplanned update to kubernetes recently broke the playground. It's now back up and should work fine on any modern OS/browser.